# specflow disabled, SpecflowPackagePackage didnt load correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bdd, specflow

[image]I am having an issue with Specflow remaining disabled in Visual Studio extensions.

When I start VS I get an error SpecflowPackagePackage didn't load correctly.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall specflow but it seems weird. When I uninstall it says uninstall successful and asks to restart VS. When I restart Specflow is still there but disabled.

Using Visual Studio 2015, Update 3, 64bit. Windows 10. Specflow Version 2017.1.6

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message text?

Comment: And which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: Added the error message I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what caused the problem. But the way I fixed was:

**NOTE** This might delete all plugins.

delete everything in below folders (with VS closed)

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
```

And reinstall the plugins along with specflow.

If someone can post a better answer please feel free to.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. However, it's happened for me on Visual Studio 2017, then I went to Control Panel/Programs and updated the Visual Studio 2017. It's worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, though I just updated from within visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the top menu -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates. On left navigation menu, be sure Installed -> All is selected. Find Specflow extension in the list and click it. Click Enable button and restart VS.

Comment: In VS 2015 it was disabled at some point indeed, so fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading Visual Studio to the latest version fixed the issue for me.**

NOTE: I believe the accepted answer works because the SpecFlow extension gets removed. If you don't need SpecFlow then uninstalling it from Tools->Extensions and Updates menu also works.

Answer (score 0):

Under `tools --> Options (settings)--> extension and updates --> Change your Extension and Update settings` , check the `Load per user extension` checkbox