# Cannot install and use Specflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bdd, specflow

I have installed Specflow on my PC at home.  It works perfectly on my PC at work.

After installing Specflow I get this error at home:

[image]

The warning references ActivityLog.xml.  Here is what ActivityLog.xml says:

```
<entry>
    <record>518</record>
    <time>2018/02/28 07:40:02.966</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [SpecFlowPackagePackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition&apos; Description: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name &quot;TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.LanguageService.IGherkinLanguageServiceFactory&quot; but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.&#x000D;&#x000A;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Expected 1 export(s) with contract name &quot;TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.LanguageService.IGherkinLanguageServiceFactory&quot; but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition importDefinition)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T](String contractName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[T]()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.Utils.VsxHelper.ResolveMefDependency[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.DefaultDependencyProvider.RegisterVsDependencies(IObjectContainer container, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.DefaultDependencyProvider.RegisterDefaults(IObjectContainer container)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.VsContainerBuilder.RegisterDefaults(IObjectContainer container)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.VsContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowPackagePackage package)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VsIntegration.SpecFlowPackagePackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{5D978B7F-8F91-41C1-B7BA-0B4C056118E8}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

How can I fix this? I have spent a long time Googling.  For example, I have looked here: [specflow disabled, SpecflowPackagePackage didnt load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631348/specflow-disabled-specflowpackagepackage-didnt-load-correctly/42696338)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1049

tl;dr: cleanup the MEF cache of Visual Studio and update to the latest version of VS 2017.

Comment: Thanks.  That did not work.  However, upgrading Visual studio to the newest subversion of Visual Studio did work as per what I believe was your post on Github (I don't have the link to the post).

Comment: Also please notice that I posted your link in my original post.

Comment: I am confused now. Is it working for you now or not? If yes, what helped?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Your post on Github helped to resolve the issue i.e. upgrade Visual Studio to latest version.  Your post on this webpage did not help.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ish, the post here is the summary of the GitHub issue.

Comment: what does lsh mean? I posted this before I saw the article on GitHub.

Comment: Do you know how I can configure Specflow to stop producing logs in the TestResult folder?

Comment: TestResult folder is created by VSTest and not by SpecFlow. All files there also depends on the test adapter you are using. It depends on this, if you can turn off logfiles. But why do you want to do this? This would be a own Stack Overflow question at its own.

Comment: Do you mean MSTest? I want to disable it whilst debugging because the folder is quite big.  I did ask another question about this earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028968/disable-the-testresults-folder

Comment: VSTest is the testing platform of Visual Studio. MSTest, like NUnit, XUnit is a test framework and they can interact with VSTest. VSTests creates the TestResult folder, the content is from the used test runner. I answered your other question.

Comment: I have asked another Specflow type question here if you are interested: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368035/using-bdd-and-ddd-approaches-which-seem-to-complement-and-contradict-each-other

Comment: @w0051977 thanks for the info, but you don't need me to inform about every question. I have notifciations enabled for the specflow tag, so I get an email for every new question.