# Disable the TestResults folder

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

How can I configure SpecFlow to stop writing logs to the TestResults folder?

I have spent the last few hours reading the documentation and I have also looked here: http://specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/

However, I am unable to find an answer.  I assume there must be an app.config setting?

Here is my app.config:

```
<specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config --><!-- use unit test provider SpecRun+NUnit or SpecRun+MsTest for being able to execute the tests with SpecRun and another provider --><unitTestProvider name="SpecRun"/><plugins>
      <add name="SpecRun"/>
    </plugins></specFlow>
```

Comment: Write a script to delete the log after the test is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logfile is generated by the SpecFlow+Runner and currently you can not disable the generation of it.
But I think this is a good idea and I will put it on our backlog.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the disclosure (extra reassurance).

Comment: I have asked another Specflow question here if you are interested in answering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366862/should-i-pass-an-id-number-from-the-feature-file

Comment: Is it possible to change the location of the test results folder? I have found this: https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Settings/.  However, outputFolder only seems to apply to the console.  I am using XUnit Visual Studio Runner.  Thanks.

Comment: The test result folder is created by VSTest. You need a runsettings file to change that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  That has worked.  Is it normal just to include the elements you want to change from the default?